# ¿sacar inversa de un matriz en modulo n?

Tags: python, matrices

Necesito la sacar la inversa de una matriz pero en modulo 29,
 [[ 6  3 26]
 [28 10  7]
 [12 22 20]]
se supone que si se le saca bien la matriz en modulo 29 quedaria de la siguiente manera:
 [[ 13 7 29]
 [1 22  11]
 [17 7 9]]

Comment: en la ultima matriz me equivoque en un numero era 28 no 29

Comment: puedes demostrar la solucion matematica porfavor

Comment: lo hice por medio de gauss jordan, pero en modulo, por ejemplo 6*5= 30 lo cual en modulo 29 es 1

Answer (score 1):

La biblioteca [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) tiene una función para eso:

```
from sympy import Matrix, pprint
A = Matrix([
  [  6,  3, 26 ],
  [ 28, 10,  7 ],
  [ 12, 22, 20 ]
])
A_inv = A.inv_mod(29)
pprint(A_inv)
```

Resultado:

```
⎡12  10  7 ⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢12  18  10⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣26  9   24⎦
```

Por cierto que esta respuesta no coincide con la que ofreces en la pregunta (aunque sí con la que te da [esta calculadora online](https://planetcalc.com/3324/))

Si te da pereza instalar Sympy y sólo lo necesitas para hacer cosas puntualmente, puedes usar [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com) que te da una interfaz a un Jupyter Notebook donde ya lo tienes preinstalado (junto con otras muchas bibliotecas típicamente útiles como numpy, pandas, matplotlib, tensorflow, etc.)